# What was the problem in this query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

```
  Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT [counts] FROM [a1_holds] WHERE (dates ='" & TextBox1.Text & "' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) AND service ='" & lab5.Text & "' ORDER BY [id] ASC", SQLData)
```

ERROR :incorrect syntax near BETWEEN

Comment: What a closing parantheses **)** doing after ASC **)**

Comment: First of all, please consider using parameters with your queries. It will save you a lot of head-aches and there are a ton of benefits from using them. Second, your `where` clause does not make much sense. You have, essentially, this in your `where` clause: `WHERE (dates ='01/01/2011' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) `. Maybe it should be something like this: `WHERE (dates BETWEEN from_date AND to_date)` and build your `from_date` and `to_date` to suit your needs. Can you give us more info about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Try testing with a date of "'); DROP DATABASE; --" to see if that fixes the problem :)  Seriously, avoid the SQL injection.  But as others have stated, remove the "dates =" text and it should work.

Comment: Yes. The SQL injection! Hackers are *really* going to have fun with this program. +1 for mentioning it -- I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT [counts] FROM [a1_holds] WHERE ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) AND service ='" & lab5.Text & "' ORDER BY [id] ASC", SQLData)
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE (dates = '...' BETWEEN ... AND ...)`

is a syntax error.  Either: `('...' BETWEEN ... AND ...)` or `(dates = '...')`